# Is it possible to enumerate a table in-memory

Tags: kdb

I want to conduct some analysis on a large table in-memory.

Firstly, will it be faster to go through the data if enumerated even in-memory?
Secondly, is there a simple way enumerate the entire table? `.Q.en` exists but that saves it as a splayed table. I could always use `get`, but is there a better way if I don't want to save the table down.

In my table, I have one column of type dictionary where the keys are symbols, the other types are either symbols, symbol lists or integers.

Thanks

Comment: If you're looking to speed up table selects you should be looking into putting attributes on columns rather than enumeration

Comment: Just as a note - `.Q.en` does not save the save the table as a splayed table. It enumerates the data, creating the sym file on disk if it is not already present, then enumerates the symbol columns against the sym file. See the [documentation for reference](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qen-enumerate-varchar-cols). `set` is used to save the table as a splayed table.

Answer (score 3):

There is no benefit to enumerating symbols in memory.
kdb+ automatically interns each unique symbol for the lifetime of the process which gives you the speed advantage without you needing to take action.

You can view their memory usage in `.Q.w[]`

- syms: number of interned symbols
- symw: bytes used by interned symbols

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qw-memory-stats